# In google sheets, how to call custom javascript comparators within sumifs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, sumifs

**What I want to do:**

In my personal accounting sheet, I'd like to have tags so I can categorize expenses into more than one bucket. For instance "food" and "kids". Some expenses are both. So for each row, besides the date, amount and other stuff, I fill a field with comma-separated tags. Then on another sheet I want to sum those up for given periods (say, a month, a quarter, or a year). So on each row i have a couple dates to define the time period, and a bunch of columns, each for one tag. I'd also like to be able to filter with more than one tag, e.g. "kids,food" so i know how much i've spent of dinner out with the kids.

With sumifs, i can select the rows within the time period, but I don't know how to do the tags.

I've already written a `function is_subset(superset, subset)`.

**What i've tried**

I've tried writing my own sumifs, but that proved difficult.

I've tried using the standard format `range, condition` with condition being `">"&A$2` but then date formats don't match. From the range, i get a string in the format `Sat Apr 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)` and from the concatenation i get ">40000" or something close, whatever that represents. I've tried to determine the format of each condition so i can parse the date, but when giving a range to a custom function, all we get are the values, not the range, so we can't access the format information from a proper `Range` object.

So i've tried passing the range strings around, e.g. `=sumifs(mysheet!A1:A, "mysheet!B1:B", "A2", "ARGLEFT>ARGRIGHT")`. So i could get a `Range`, check the format, then replace ARGLEFT and ARGRIGHT and call `eval`, but then i can't copy and paste the formula around anymore since the ranges won't get adjusted. And testing for all formats would be a pain anyways.

**What i think might work, if only...**

The closest i've got is using eval with custom functions always:
`=sumifs(mysheet!A1:A, mysheet!B1:B, A2, "gt")`

I wrote `function lt(left,right){return left<right;}`, gt, gte, lte, eq, and now i can use my initial `is_subset`, too. But this only works if i give it CELLS, not RANGES. Cells compare properly: `=test(A1, A2, "gt")` is fine. Ranges do not: `=test_loop(A1:A5, A2, "gt")` returns wrong values.

[Here's a link to a prototype sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CY-08SeiX-jSOZ0K3xOz28BMg0LL8gYNK8LWLeAt2rg/edit?usp=sharing).

This link will eventually be broken, so here are screenshots:

Sheet `Balance` containing all money movements:
[image: Sheet "Balance" containing all money movements]

Sheet `Expenses` containing the formula i'm looking for:
[image: Sheet "Expenses" containing the formula i'm looking for]

Here's the formula i have so far for `Expenses!D2`:

```
=mysumifs(Balance!$E$3:$E, Balance!$A$3:$A, $A2, "gte", Balance!$A$3:$A, $B2, "lt", Balance!$B$3:$B, "Expense", "eq", Balance!$D$3:$D, D$1, "is_subset")
```

Here's the full code:

```
function is_subset(superset, subset)
{
  subset = subset.toLowerCase().split(",")
  superset = superset.toLowerCase().split(",")
  for (var i = 0 ; i < subset.length ; i++)
  {
    var found = false;
    for (var j = 0 ; j < superset.length ; j++)
    {
      if (subset[i] == superset[j])
      {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if ( ! found)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
function gt (left,right) { return left> right; }
function gte(left,right) { return left>=right; }
function lt (left,right) { return left< right; }
function lte(left,right) { return left<=right; }
function eq (left,right) { return left==right; }
function mysumifs()
{
  if ((arguments.length % 3) != 1)
    throw "Bad arg count";
  var range_to_sum = arguments[0];
  var sum = 0;
  for (row_idx = 0 ; row_idx < range_to_sum.length ; row_idx++)
  {
    Logger.log("row_idx: " + row_idx);
    var add = true;
    for (arg_idx=1 ; add && arg_idx<arguments.length ; arg_idx+=3)
    {
      Logger.log("arg_idx: " + arg_idx);
      try
      {
        var left_range = arguments[arg_idx];
        if (range_to_sum.length != left_range.length)
          throw "Ranges have differente sizes";
        left = left_range[row_idx];
        Logger.log("left: " + left);
        var right = arguments[arg_idx+1];
        Logger.log("right: " + right);
        var op = eval(arguments[arg_idx+2]);
        Logger.log("op: " + op);
        Logger.log("op(left,right): " + op(left,right));
        
        if ( ! op(left, right))
          add = false;
      } catch(error){
          add = false;
          Logger.log("exception: " + error)
      }
    }
    if (add)
      sum += range_to_sum[row_idx][0];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Am I missing something obvious about sumifs that would allow to use arbitrary, custom comparators?

Did I make a mistake about reading values from given ranges?

Comment: Hmm, I think you need to add a link to an example with data for a full-fledged example.

Comment: @contributorpw Yes, you're right. I've edited the question, but here's the link nonetheless: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CY-08SeiX-jSOZ0K3xOz28BMg0LL8gYNK8LWLeAt2rg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `with data for a full-fledged example.` Hi. Your example needs to include an example of a successful outcome - you do the calculations and enter the results manually. It's really very difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve without knowing what outcome you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what if you used this formula `=transpose(query({Balance!A3:E19},"select Col4, Sum(Col5) where Col1 is not null and Col2 matches 'Expense' and Col1 > date '"&TEXT(A2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(B2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'group by Col4 label Sum(Col5) ''"))` in cell D1 of the "Expenses" sheet? (and delete the existing contents of D1:G2). Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Tedinoz Well, almost. You solution brings all unique text in column D ("To"), but doesn't treat it as a list of tags, so i can't come up with an arbitrary combination of tags on the Expenses sheet. However, you sir have shown me the light and i've found the solution to the date format problem using value and arrayformula. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

I was able to fix the date format compatibility problem using `value()` to force the date format into something easily comparable and `arrayformula()` to make it so for a range. I did not need to alter my javascript functions. Here's the correct call for `Expenses!D2`:

```
=mysumifs(Balance!$E$3:$E, arrayformula(value(Balance!$A$3:$A)), value($A2), "gte", arrayformula(value(Balance!$A$3:$A)), value($B2), "lt", Balance!$B$3:$B, "Expense", "eq", Balance!$D$3:$D, D$1, "is_subset")
```

With:

- `Balance!$E$3:$E` being the values to be summed
- `Balance!$A$3:$A` the date of each "event"
- `$A2` the period's start date
- `gte` the custom javascript function (check the code in the question) to compare the start date and the event's date
- `Balance!$A$3:$A`, `$B2` and `lt` to check that the event's date is before the period's end date
- `Balance!$B$3:$B`, `Expense`, `eq` says the event's type must be equal to `Expense`
- `Balance!$D$3:$D`, `D$1`, `is_subset`, says the column's header must be a tag subset of the `To` column of the event.

The data:
[image]

The Formula:
[image]

Comment: Would you please include a snapshot that shows the outcome of formula/script?

Comment: @Tedinoz There you go